# Creating a map with keys based on values of a different map?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I'm trying to come up with the .map call that would use a certain field of a dict as key of the result:

```
input=[ {key:"name", value:"John"}, {key:"city", value:"Chicago"}]

output = input.map( e => **magic here** );
>> output = [ {name:"John"}, {city:"Chicago"}]
```

I've tried from `input.map( e => { e.name:e.value})`, to no avail.
Also tried `input.map(({key, value}) => ({key:value}))`, but it does not populate the key value correctly - rather taking "key" as the key of the dicts.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could destructure the object and take [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) for a new object.

```js
const
    input = [{ key: "name", value: "John" }, { key: "city", value: "Chicago" }],
    output = input.map(({ key, value }) => ({ [key]: value }));

console.log(output);
```